# Can I compress two rows with a difference in two columns into a single row with both columns?

Tags: postgresql, query, pivot, row

I have a query that returns customer product information that shows which region a product is sourced from.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    prod.prod_id, 
    prod.is_source,
    link.prod_link_disabled, 
    loc.location_id, 
    loc.customer_id, 
    cust.customer_name
FROM 
    product prod, 
    product_link link, 
    region region, 
    location loc, 
    customer cust
WHERE 
    prod.prod_id = link.prod_id
    AND link.region_id = region.region_id
    AND region.loc_id = loc.loc_id
    AND link.prod_link_deleted = FALSE
    AND loc.customer_id = customer_id
    AND prod.prod_id = 5874;
```

This returns the following result:

```
| prod_id             | is_source | prod_link_disabled | location_id | customer_id | customer_name   |
| ------------------- | --------- | ------------------ | ----------- | ----------- | --------------- |
| Test Product - 5874 |         t |                  f |           2 |         332 | Test Playground |
| Test Product - 5874 |         f |                  f |           1 |         332 | Test Playground |
```

This is showing that product 5874 is coming from location 2 (because `is_source` is true).

I'd like to compress this information into a single row. I'd like a result that looks like this:

```
| prod_id             | prod_link_disabled | src_location_id | dest_location_id | customer_id | customer_name   |
| ------------------- | ------------------ | --------------- | ---------------- | ----------- | --------------- |
| Test Product - 5874 |                  f |               2 |                1 |         332 | Test Playground |
```

This compressed the two previous rows into a single row where `src_location_id` is `2` (again because that row had `is_source` as true) and `dest_location_id` is `1`

How can I pivot the two row result into a single row?

It is safe to assume that there are always only two results in the first query.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly and you need something like:

```
SELECT prod1.prod_id, 
       link1.prod_link_disabled, 
       loc1.location_id AS src_location_id, 
       loc1.location_id AS dst_location_id, 
       loc1.customer_id, 
       cust1.customer_name
  FROM product AS prod1 
  JOIN product_link AS link1 ON link1.prod_id = prod1.prod_id
  JOIN region AS region1 ON region1.region_id = link1.region_id
  JOIN location AS loc1 ON loc1.loc_id = region1.loc_id
  JOIN customer AS cust1 ON cust1.customer_id = loc1.customer_id
  JOIN product AS prod2 ON prod2.prod_id = prod1.prod_id
  JOIN product_link AS link2 ON link2.prod_id = prod2.prod_id
  JOIN region AS region2 ON region2.region_id = link2.region_id
  JOIN location AS loc2 ON loc2.loc_id = region2.loc_id
  JOIN customer AS cust2 ON cust2.customer_id = loc2.customer_id
 WHERE prod1.is_source AND
       NOT link1.prod_link_deleted AND
       NOT prod2.is_source AND
       NOT link2.prod_link_deleted AND
       prod1.prod_id = 5874;
```

Sure, you can remove excessive JOINs.